# using $filter on tapkey endpoints

Tags: tapkey

I'm making a call to this endpoint `/api/v1/Owners/{ownerAccountId}/BoundLocks` to get boundLocks associated with an ownerAccount, but I would like to filter those based on title,

This is what I'm doing but it still returns all the locks:

```
        `${this.baseUrl}/owners/${this.ownerAccountId}/BoundLocks?filter=title eq '${lockId}`,
        {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
          }
        }
      )
      return boundLocks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the original code? The code uses `filter` not `$filter` as query parameter and the lockId seems not to be quoted correctly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-odata/72d4ebf9-5480-49a4-b88b-c5782f726c87

Answer (score 0):

I was filtering incorrectly:

```
        `${this.baseUrl}/owners/${this.ownerAccountId}/BoundLocks?$filter=title eq '${lockId}'`,
        {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
          }
        }
      )
      return boundLocks
```